# Title Case is not working in Angular Schema Form

Tags: angularjs, regex, jsonschema, angular-schema-form

How do you require title case in a field rendered using [Angular Schema Form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form).

EG. `^([A-Z][^\s]*\s?)+$`

Please provide the inputs.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue please mark it as the answer @vijay-thanda

Answer (score 0):

An example for the appropriate pattern definition to be provided in the schema would be:

```
{
  "title": "My string",
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "^([A-Z][a-z]*[\\s]*)*$"
}
```

You may need to add further exceptions but that will cover basic title case.